# What does 0 in printf( 0, "%d", num) do?

Tags: c, arguments, printf, xv6

I usually code in C++, but I'm working on a project in C and I came across a printf with the following syntax:

```
printf( 0, "%d\n", num);
```

I've looked around and can't find an explanation of what the first 0 in the printf does.  Can someone please explain it to me?  Thanks.

Comment: Because you should get warnings for this! `[Warning] null argument where non-null required (argument 1) [-Wnonnull]` and `[Warning] too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]`

Comment: Are you sure it's not `fprintf` ?

Comment: @PaulR even if it was `fprintf()` the same thing just `(FILE *)0`... unless it's `dprintf()` which prints to a file descriptor and is specified in **POSIX.1-2008**.

Comment: @Rizier123 "Because"?! Doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [xv6](https://github.com/Travis-Xiao/xv6-reform/blob/master/printf.c) is not using `printf` from the standard library. The first argument is a file descriptor indicating which stream to write to:

```
void
printf(int fd, char *fmt, ...)
{
    char *s;
    int c, i, state;
    uint *ap;
    state = 0;
    ap = (uint*)(void*)&fmt + 1;
    for(i = 0; fmt[i]; i++){
        c = fmt[i] & 0xff;
        if(state == 0){
            if(c == '%'){
                state = '%';
            } else {
                putc(fd, c);
            }
        } else if(state == '%'){
            if(c == 'd'){
                printint(fd, *ap, 10, 1);
                ap++;
            } else if(c == 'x' || c == 'p'){
                printint(fd, *ap, 16, 0);
                ap++;
            } else if(c == 's'){
                s = (char*)*ap;
                ap++;
                if(s == 0)
                    s = "(null)";
                while(*s != 0){
                    putc(fd, *s);
                    s++;
                }
            } else if(c == 'c'){
                putc(fd, *ap);
                ap++;
            } else if(c == '%'){
                putc(fd, c);
            } else {
            // Unknown % sequence. Print it to draw attention.
                putc(fd, '%');
                putc(fd, c);
            }
            state = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **wow** they really used that name for such function, even when there is a `dprintf()` specified in **POSIX.1-2008**?

Answer (score 1):

It is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior); I guess you might have a segmentation violation.

Comment: This compiles, runs, and prints the statement.  I'm seeing it in code for xv6.

Comment: @Caulibrot dereferencing a `NULL` pointer is undefined behavior, so any behavior is possible because it's **undefined**, it could be **segmentation fault** or it could work, or whatever other behavior, it's **undefined**...

Comment: @kamituel I dont think so, if it was `write(0 ... ` ok, but in this case the OP passed `0` for the format string which will be dereferenced without checking it for `NULL` in `printf()`.

Comment: I've found the following function in an assembly (ls.asm) file for xv6: void printf( int fd, char * fmt, ... )  I'm guessing this uses the 0 somehow, but I'm not sure how exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf( 0, "%d\n", num);
```

invokes undefined behavior because the first argument of `printf` has to be a pointer to a string.

Comment: Obviously not on xv6.