# What does putting an integer as the first argument to printf() do?

Tags: c, printf, xv6

What does putting an integer as the argument to printf(*someIntHere*, "*somestring*") do?

I'm wondering if this is specific to creating a user program in the xv6 operating system, which is why I added that detail. When the user "runs my command", I want to output something. However, I'd assume printf() wouldn't need that first integer argument, but I keep seeing examples of it everywhere.

For example, I am adding a user program to the xv6 operating system and all of the printf() examples here have something like:

`printf(1, "Some text happened here");`

`printf(2, "Some other text is over here");`

`fprintf(2, "find: cannot open %s\n", path);`

I can't find documentation anywhere that explains this clearly, I'm sorry if the answer is obvious I'm just so confused and I don't understand why I can't just:

`printf("Some text happened here");`

Comment: Where have you seen any such examples? Do not say the examples are “something like”; give the exact actual text of the examples, and give a URL for where you found them or, if you found them in print rather than online, give a bibliographic citation for them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28904073/459640

Comment: Short answer: Evidently xv6 uses its own, *nonstandard* `printf` function (but, most confusingly, using the exact same name as the standard function).